# Pyhtonnet - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DllName'

Tags: python, python.net

I have create a project .Net core 3.1 web API project and published the project..

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
    BusinessLayer.BusinessLayer b = new BusinessLayer.BusinessLayer();

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public List<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return b.Get();
    }
}
}
```

getting below error "**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'WebApplication1'**" when i refer the dll in the python project using pythonnet. here the code for pythonnet

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import clr
import sys

assemblykdir = r"C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\BusinessLayer\WebApplication1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1"
sys.path.append(assemblykdir)
clr.AddReference("WebApplication1")

from WebApplication1.Controllers import WeatherForecastController
weatherForecast = WeatherForecastController()
aa = weatherForecast.Get()
```

When i use project type class library then it is working